# Удаление записи по истечению срока установленого ползователем

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Есть записть в таблице, она может храниться в ней не меньше 2 часов и не более 7 дней.

Как лучше это реализовать? Использовать `cron` или тригером в базе данных `postgresql`?

Comment: Триггер тут неприменим - он выполняется только при каком-то действии (не выборка!) с данными. Так что только планировщик (если в PostgreSQL нет встроенного - то системный).

Comment: Однако можно просто на уровне серверной или клиентской логики не использовать записи, которые протухли (всего-то одно дополнительное условие во WHERE). Заодно и история теряться не будет...